# Do I need a passport to leave the UK if my destination doesn't need me to have one?

Tags: passports, borders, uk-citizens

Following on from this question: [Will I be eligible for an Emergency Travel Document?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49837/will-i-be-eligible-for-an-emergency-travel-document), I'm wondering:

If the US doesn't require a passport if I'm entering on a Green Card, does the UK require me to have one to leave?

If not, would me Green Card be sufficient identification to check in and board my plane?

Who makes this call? UK Border Agency? My airline? Someone else?

Comment: Watch out: you might need it on your way back!

Comment: Your Airline will need to assure itself that you have sufficient documents and permission to be let into the destination country, otherwise they risk fines!

Comment: @lohoris I can get a fast track renewal in one day in the UK

Comment: The UK Border Force makes the call (UKBA was disbanded a good while back), but ultimately Parliament makes the law.  Your current passport is ok for both entry and exit.  But I don't know squat about the American side of the pond.  Just British.

Answer (score 1):

There's no law that you require a passport (in date or otherwise) to leave the UK.

It's simply up to the airline whether they wish to transport you to the destination. They will not transport you if they think you will be denied entry, because the airline gets fined for this.

Comment: I'll try to find a source for this later, a bit hard to prove a negative

Comment: It's not really proof - but it does make sense: When leaving, your documentation is checked at Check-In by airline personnel. When arriving, you go through immigration control and will deal with the countries Border Agency. There are generally few restrictions on leaving a country, but countries tend to be picky about who they let in!

Comment: I am not sure whether the airlines get fined if a passenger is denied entry. I think they only have to take him back to the origin, which won't be a problem for the airline, if the ticket is a return ticket.

Comment: @QuoraFeans for example, here is the U.S. penalties list for the carrier http://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/documents/carrier_info_guide.pdf see page 57

Comment: @Calchas Your link is now dead